# Redirecting to another page in browser using html

Tags: html

i want to redirect my image to another website using simple html, how to do that.

by clicking on the image another browser tab should open up and should open that link predefined in the image.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://put.your.site.here.com" target="_blank">
 <img src="http://put.path.to.image.here" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

But the problem is that it is redirecting it to the new tab. But with both the urls.

Like: www.google.com/www.newurl.com